# Modal window is not popping up in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a link to trigger ajax, which should pop up a window and I am not able to do that. I am using gem 'bootstrap-modal-rails', and I am trying with the following code

//index/html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Link', load_users_teams_path(format: "js"), remote: true %>
<div id="id"></div>

<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

//controller

```
def load_users
    @user = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

//load_users.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'teams/load_users' ) %>");
$("#modal-window").modal()
```

//load_users.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
   <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
   **here comes whatever you want to show!**
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
 </div>
```

Tired of trying this since a week.. please guide me

Comment: Is that `#` in your .js causing it? Try adding it to the other one, as well as taking it away from both, etc.

Comment: no i just missed it while copying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added few gems in gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.4.0'
gem 'sassc-rails', '>= 2.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-modal-rails'
```

mentioned these under application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= twitter-bootstrap
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-modal
//= require bootstrap-modalmanager
```

mentioned these under application.js

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-modal-bs3patch
 *= require bootstrap-modal
```

changed the application.html.erb's body

```
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="span9"><%= yield %></div>
    <div id="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" style="z-index: 9999;" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="z-index: 9999;" ></div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </body>
```

_load_user.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="modal-window">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
<div class="modal-body">
here comes whatever you want to show!
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

load_user.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript( render "load_users") %>");
$("#modal-window").modal();
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Link' ,load_users_teams_path, remote: true %>
```

this fixed my problem, actually  my code at new.html.erb was clashing with application.html.erb file and some gems were missing